# Redis is running on protected mode

Tags: configuration, redis, streaming, benchmarking

I am trying to run Extended Yahoo Benchmark on 4 VMs. Everytime I try to run 'STORM_TEST' I get the following error. I tried configuring 'redis.conf' but still get the same error. I have shown below both the error and my 'redis.conf' file.

ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password is requested to clients. In this mode connections are only accepted from the loopback interface. If you want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions: 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the server. 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one of the above things in order for the server to start accepting connections from the outside.

at redis.protocol$read_error_reply.invoke(protocol.clj:86)
at redis.protocol$read_reply.invoke(protocol.clj:119)
at redis.connection$send_command_and_read_reply.invoke(connection.clj:42)
at redis.connection$make_connection.invoke(connection.clj:75)
at redis.connection_pool$make_connection_factory$reify__495.makeObject(connection_pool.clj:21)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1190)
at redis.connection_pool.ConnectionPool.get_connection(connection_pool.clj:11)
at setup.core$do_new_setup.invoke(core.clj:211)
at setup.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:284)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:388)
at user$eval5.invoke(form-init4687907619169214448.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6782)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6772)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7227)
... 11 more
```

REDIS.CONF:

```
bind 127.0.0.1
protected-mode no
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize no
supervised no
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
loglevel notice
logfile ""
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 300
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried the steps given in the exception?  I guess, doing those itself will solve the issue

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing redis.conf? What is the command used for running Redis?

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall and Pascal Le Merrer: Thank you both for your quick replies. Yeah I tried the second step of changing the 'redis.conf' and then restart the server. But it seemed redis was not looking into that file. Then I manually gave the path to configuration file in my script when starting redis and then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should make the reference to your config file

```
26399:C 16 Jan 08:51:13.413 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use ./redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

you can try to start your redis server like

```
./redis-server /path/to/redis-stable/redis.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am not doing that project now. So, I could not try your way. But your answer would be helpful to someone. :-)